# Chrome Extension : While Capturing Desktop, selected Window is focused in front

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

So guys I have a chrome extension that captures image of selected desktop window using `chrome.desktopCapture` , `navigator.webkitGetUserMedia` and `canvas`. When I ask user to select the window to share from, the selected window gets focused to front.

Here's my code -

manifest.json -

```
{
  "name": "Desktop Capture Example",
  "description": "Show desktop media picker UI",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
     "persistent": false,
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
    "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Take a screen shot of Desktop!"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "desktopCapture"
  ]
}
```

background.js -

```
var pending_request_id = null;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {

   pending_request_id = chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(["screen", "window"],onAccessApproved);

});

function gotStream(stream) {
  console.log("Received local stream");
  var video = document.createElement('video');
  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',function(){
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = this.videoWidth;
      canvas.height = this.videoHeight;
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
      var url = canvas.toDataURL();
      console.log(url);
      // will open the captured image in a new tab
      //window.open(url);
    },false);
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  video.play();
  }

function getUserMediaError() {
  console.log("getUserMedia() failed.");
}

function onAccessApproved(id) {
  if (!id) {
    console.log("Access rejected.");
    return;
  }
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
      audio:false,
      video: { mandatory: { chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
                            chromeMediaSourceId: id,
                            maxWidth: 4000,
                            maxHeight: 4000} }
  }, gotStream, getUserMediaError);
}
```

However if  I use `window.open(url)`, focus is set to this opened window not the shared window. But instead of using window.open if I use `chrome.tabs.create({url: url,active : true},function(tab){})` to open the url, shared window gets focused on top of opened tab.I want the opened tab to focus not shared window.How to I do this?

Comment: I don't understand what is your question here.

Comment: @Xan Lets suppose I want to capture the screenshot of Skype window. My code generates the screenshot of this window and open this is in new chrome tab using window.open(), this opened chrome window has current focus but if I use chrome.tabs.create, tab is opened but Skype gets focused on top of it.

Comment: "Yes". Does that answer your question? Because I still don't see anything formulated as a question.

Comment: No I want the opened tab to have the focus not skype window

Comment: So, to reformulate, you want to open a tab in an existing window and then focus on it?

Comment: @Xan Yes, that's exactly what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Brian's answer, you want to make the window focused too after you've created a tab that's active in that window.

This is made similarly:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: url, active: true}, function(tab) {
  chrome.windows.update(tab.windowId, {focused: true});
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted

Comment: Also Brian's answer works too if I use chrome.tabs.update in callback of chrome.tabs.create. Can you explain the difference between two?

Comment: No, I cannot. The documentation for `active` specifically says: _"Whether the tab should be active. Does not affect whether the window is focused"_

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use the chrome.tabs api to switch the active tab via the update method: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update

Prior to Chrome 33, you would do this:

```
chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {selected: true});
```

I believe this changed to this:

```
chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {active: true});
```

Depending on the way the tabs are aligned, you may also need the chrome.windows api: chrome.windows.update, take a look at the focused parameter (also mentioned in chrome.tabs api docs).

EDIT: Had wrong property being set, corrected.